# New type of TVS diode - where do I find one, if it even exists?

Tags: tvs, transient-suppression

I've been looking at various TVS's and recently came across one I'd never seen before:

[image: Low Capacitance Clamping Diode]

This particular part is used by Citel for a transient suppression, and concluded that this part had been released out in the world recently.  It seems to be the equivalent solid-state version of a three-pole gas discharge tube.

Wishing to find a datasheet for said "DBC", I performed a Google search for some manufacturer, but ended up turning up nothing. I couldn't even find a theoretical reference.

So my question: is  this a proprietary part by made by Citel, or is it a generic part that I did not recognize that is in common use, but failed to enter the correct search terms for?

Comment: Do you have a BOM for this board? Can you share the reference where you found this?

Comment: No, I don't.  I downloaded various Citel catalogs in hopes of zooming in on the components and at least getting a possible part number or manufacturer.  Pixilation killed that idea.

Comment: Oh, yeah the [link](https://citel.us/serverFile/getPdfFile/2190510)

Answer (score 1):

The [Citel main catalog (sorry, German only)](https://www.citel.de/de/hauptkatalog) shows several arrestors that use the DBC suppressors.

For example, the CGMJ8-POE-A:

[image]

It clearly has rows of diodes protecting the lines, as well as gas discharge tubes.

If the DBC just means "three low capacitance diodes" then that would match the diagram that goes with the CGMJ8-POE-A:

[image]

Given that, I'd say that DBC is just the Citel designation for using three low capacitance diodes on each line rather than designating some Citel made part.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Citel documentation](http://citel.us/serverFile/getFile?fileId=1522328), components with this symbol are called "3-pole clamping diodes" and "3-pole low-capacitance diodes".

I don't know if this is a new 3-pole TVS semiconductor device, or just a compact way of drawing three Zener diodes with common cathodes, intended to be connected between data+, data-, and ground, but I strongly suspect it is the latter, and not a new kind of component.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the General Catalog (p. 106) that for a B180, which suggest a single pair, I note that there are six TVS(?) as well as the resistors and the single GDT. There is one component that is unknown on the very top.  Per the illustration in JDR's answer, it seems there would only be a need for three diodes.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkMTn.png]

Regardless, I'll conclude that DBC or D3 schematic symbol literally is an amalgamation of three discrete diodes rather than a single discrete diode.
Thanks to all for your perspectives.